# check if the number of rows in matrix equals to given rows in c

Tags: c, matrix, user-input, rows

I need to check if the number of rows in a matrix is same as given rows. The user inputs size of the matrix and then the elements of the matrix. Here is my code to take the input:

```
int **mat1, row, col;
scanf("%d %d", &row, &col);

mat1 = (int**) malloc (sizeof(int*) * row);
for(int i = 0; i < row; ++i){
    mat1[i] = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int) * col);
}

for(int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
        scanf("%d", &mat1[i][j]);
    }
    scanf("\n");
}
```

I want to check the case, when the user wants for example 2 rows but then inputs only one

2 3 //number of rows and columns

1 2 3 //inputs only one row

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: You'll have to show a [mcve] of what you have tried. The `sizeof()` approach won't work because if `arr` is really an array it has constant size, and if it is a pointer to memory that dynamically grows as the user inputs rows, `sizeof` will only give you the size of the pointer, not the size of the memory it points to.

Comment: that won't even compile. As I said, please read [mcve] and *update your question* with your *complete* code. Don't use the comments to add things to your question.

Comment: Also, always check return value of scanf. Read docs to learn what it can return.

Comment: `while (scanf("%d", &mat1[i][j])!=1) printf("Not understood; try again\n");`

Answer (score 0):

You know that there was an input error when `scanf()` doesn't return the number of conversion specifiers in the format string (= the number of fields, it is supposed to read). Since you always try to read 1 integer, check if `scanf()` returns something different than 1:

```
int input_successful = 1;  // assume input is ok
for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
        if (scanf(" %d", &mat1[i][j]) != 1) {
            //     ^ this makes sure that the '\n' from last line is ignored
            input_successful = 0;  // remember input is flawed
            i = row;               // make sure the outer loop ends immediatly
            break;                 // break out of the inner loop
        }
    }
    // scanf("\n");   // unnecessary
}

if (!input_successful) {
    // handle error
}

// ...

// and free() the allocated memory when you are done using it!
```